# Totally ordered groups

Tags: group-theory

Is there a group equipped with a total order $\leq$, such that $x\leq y$ implies $x*z \leq y*z$, but not always $z*x \leq z*y$.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately there's a bunch of people here erasing without nuance all brief questions on the ground that no context is given.

Comment: @YCor Why should some questions be exempt from the rule? I mean this one doesn't even contain a single question mark. Also, on hold $\neq$ erase.

Comment: @limitsandlogs224 The "rule" only depends on those who claim it, some of who applying it independently to questions of standard undergraduate level and of post-graduate level. I'm quite happy that the average voting level on MathOF is based on less mechanical "rules".

Comment: I tend to take the "no context given" as more "no work or progress shown" which is the case here.

Comment: I understand, and I regret the tendency to consider every question here as homework regardless of its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For instance, for $m\in\mathbf{Z}\smallsetminus\{0\}$, consider the semidirect product $G_m=\mathbf{Z}[1/m]\rtimes_{m}\mathbf{Z}$, where the generator $+1$ acts on the normal subgroup by multiplication by $m$.

Define
$$P=\{(u,n)\in \mathbf{Z}[1/m]\rtimes_{m}\mathbf{Z}:\;n>0\text{ or }(n=0\text{ and }u>0)\}.$$

Then $PP\subset P$, and $G_m=P\sqcup\{e\}\sqcup P^{-1}$. Hence, defining $g<h$ iff $gh^{-1}\in P$ defines a right-invariant total ordering on $G_m$. However, $P$ is conjugation-invariant iff $m>0$. Hence for $m<0$ (including $m=-1$: fundamental group of the Klein bottle) this ordering is not left-invariant.

Actually it is not hard to prove that for $m<0$, there is no bi-invariant total ordering on $G_m$.